# Access to Web Folder from Console application Yii2

Tags: yii2

[image]Inside my console application I have to download some images and save it under /web/images , but it said directory doesn't exist. If I inside web application I can access /web folder normally.

Please help!!!

Comment: You should post up your folder structure so we can see where you're console application sits in comparison to your web directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `aliases` property in to your console application config in your case *config/console.php*:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@webimages' => dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'web' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images',
]
```

And then in your console application code call `Yii::getAlias('@webimages')` to get path to your web directory.

Comment: FYI Yii2 also has a fair amount of pre-defined aliases that you can use for this type of thing as well: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#predefined-aliases